# Specialization impl does not specialize any associated items

Tags: ink, rust, wasm, cargo, openbrush

I'm fairly new to Rust and ink! itself.

I'm trying to compile and build an extremely basic PSP22 Contract.

**I get the following error when I compile & build:**

(running `cargo +nightly contract build`)

[image]

The following is my **Contract** (`lib.rs`) :

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
#![feature(min_specialization)]
        
#[openbrush::contract]
pub mod my_psp22 {
    
    // imports from openbrush
    use openbrush::contracts::psp22::*;
    use openbrush::traits::Storage;

    #[ink(storage)]
    #[derive(Default, Storage)]
    pub struct Ipsp22 {
        #[storage_field]
        psp22: psp22::Data,
    }
    
    // Section contains default implementation without any modifications
    impl PSP22 for Ipsp22 {}
     
    impl Ipsp22 {
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new(initial_supply: Balance) -> Self {
            let mut _instance = Self::default();
            _instance._mint_to(_instance.env().caller(), initial_supply).expect("Should mint"); 
            _instance
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my **Cargo.toml** :

```
[package]
name = "my_token"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["0xD1x0n"]
edition = "2021"
license = "Apache 2.0"

[dependencies]
ink = { version = "~4.0.0", default-features = false }
openbrush = { git = "https://github.com/727-Ventures/openbrush-contracts/", tag = "3.0.0", default-features = false, features = ["psp22", "ownable"] }

scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }

[lib]
name = "my_token"
path = "lib.rs"
crate-type = [
    "cdylib",
    "rlib",
]

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "ink/std",
    "scale/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "openbrush/std",
]
ink-as-dependency = []
```

**I am using the following versions of these tools:**

- rustc 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16)
- cargo-contract-contract 2.2.1-91b5a86-aarch64-apple-darwin
- rustup 1.26.0 (5af9b9484 2023-04-05)

I'm not quite sure why its happening, any help would be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by using this as my **`Cargo.toml`** :

```
[package]
name = "alephcontract"
version = "1.0.0"
edition = "2021"
authors = ["0xD1x0n"]

[dependencies]
ink = { version = "4.2.1", default-features = false }
scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }

openbrush = { git = "https://github.com/727-Ventures/openbrush-contracts", tag = "3.1.0", default-features = false, features = ["psp22","ownable",]}

[lib]
name = "alephcontract"
path = "lib.rs"
crate-type = [
    # Used for normal contract Wasm blobs.
    "cdylib",
    "rlib",
]

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "ink/std",
    "scale/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "openbrush/std",
]

psp22 = ["openbrush/psp22"]
ink-as-dependency = []
```

I compiled the contract using **toolchain `+nightly-2023-01-01`** by executing the following command :

```
cargo +nightly-2023-01-01 contract build --release
```

Answer (score 1):

I made these changes to your code and it compiled successfully:

[image: changes to code shown in the question to make it work]

I was using these versions:

```
rustc 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16)
cargo-contract-contract 3.0.1-unknown-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup 1.26.0 (5af9b9484 2023-04-05)
```

I was running it in a Docker container running:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
```

I ran it with the following and it worked:

```bash
cargo +nightly-2023-03-21-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu contract build
```

Comment: Could you share your Docker file ?

Comment: I got this error along with hundreds other similar to it : error[E0152]: duplicate lang item in crate `alloc` (which `std` depends on): `owned_box`.

Comment: i've added it in this PR https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/pull/17/files#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5R166 including instructions. so just need to install Docker then run something like `touch .env && cp .env.example .env && time ./docker/docker.sh`, then run `docker exec -it ink /bin/bash` in two terminals, and inside one terminal start a substrate-contracts-node with `cd /app && ./docker/reset.sh`, and in the other terminal run `cd /app && ./docker/quickstart-ipsp22.sh` to build and deploy and instantiate that smart contract

Comment: the dockerfile that it uses is here https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/blob/main/docker/Dockerfile

Comment: I got to the part where I open up 2 terminals using : `docker exec -it ink /bin/bash`.

Looks like there is no app folder in it. the docker folder it contains only has a run.sh file in it.

Comment: not on my computer now but I think it's because you need to change this line in Dockerfile:
RUN ./docker/run.sh ${WITHOUT_NODE} ${DEBIAN_CODENAME} ${HOME} ${RUST_NIGHTLY} ${CARGO_CONTRACT_VERSION} ${SUBSTRATE_CONTRACTS_NODE_VERSION} ${NODE_VERSION_MAJOR}

Comment: and add the following in run.sh right after `WITHOUT_NODE=$1`
DEBIAN_CODENAME=$2
HOME=$3
RUST_NIGHTLY=$4
CARGO_CONTRACT_VERSION=$5
SUBSTRATE_CONTRACTS_NODE_VERSION=$6
NODE_VERSION_MAJOR=$7

Comment: run the following to stop and remove the container before you run the commands again `docker stop ink && docker rm ink` and see if there are any errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146819/discussion-between-luke-schoen-and-0xd1x0n).